# onclick preforming 2 functions

Tags: javascript, function, iframe, multiple-instances

I can't seem to get this to work the way I want it to. I have an iframe with content in it and I want to be able to click the Next button and have the iframe advance by 1 and have it show the url below the frame, and also advance by 1.
I am aware of the issues with calling back the iframe url, but it's only advancing by 1 each time so I figured if I just have it output the url+clicks it would keep up with the actual url of the page.
Separately I have made both codes work but when I put them together it doesn't seem to work.

```
<script>
var c=0;
var url="http://www.example.com/myfolders/";
var clicks=0;
var burl="http://www.example.com/myfolders/";
function func1(){
 document.getElementById("myframe").src = url+c;
 c++;
}
function func2() {
    clicks += 1;
    document.getElementById("myframe").innerHTML = burl+clicks;
};
</script>

<iframe id="myframe" sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-popups allow-forms" src="http://www.example.com/myfolders/0" width="100%" height="300"></iframe>

<input type=button onclick="func1();func2();" value="Next">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is getting the iframe (through `document.getElementById("myframe")`) and **setting its innerHTML**. You can't do this. After your iframe, create an element to act as a legend and set its innerHTML to the iframe URL. It would be something like this (code is improved too):

```
<script>
var c=0;
var url="http://www.example.com/myfolders/";
var clicks=0;
var burl="http://www.example.com/myfolders/";
function updateFrame() {
    clicks++;
    c++;
    document.getElementById("myframe").src = url+c; 
    document.getElementById("framelegend").innerHTML = burl+clicks;
};
</script>

<iframe id="myframe" sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-popups allow-forms" src="http://www.example.com/myfolders/0" width="100%" height="300"></iframe>
<span id="framelegend"></span>

<input type=button onclick="updateFrame();" value="Next">
```

Comment: This really helped. Thanks for the explanation, I leaned something new!

Answer (score 0):

why not call function in another function.Maybe can do something like this.Hope this help to solve your issue

```
function func1(){
 document.getElementById("myframe").src = url+c;
 c++;
}
function func2() {
 clicks += 1;
 document.getElementById("myframe").innerHTML = burl+clicks;
}
function todo(){
c1();
func2();
}

<input type=button onclick="todo();" value="Next">
```